# Open layers maps, with longitude and latitude get address

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am trying to get address(City, Post code,Street address) with longitude and latitude but i don`t know how. I am using Open layers and when i click on part of map  a get longitude and latitude of that position. Does anybody have solution for this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mouse Position</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.0/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script>
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [2918616.660738325,4873187.634331534],
      zoom: 19
    })
  });
 
   map.on('click', function (evt) {
    var coord = ol.proj.toLonLat(evt.coordinate);
    alert(coord);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

what you are looking for is "reverse geocoding". A good example of what that looks like is shown here: https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/26e61508217ba86a04c19a67cbda0e99

In your case that would roughly translate to:

```
function reverseGeocode(coords) {
   fetch('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lon=' + coords[0] + '&lat=' + coords[1])
     .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(json) {
            console.log(json);
        });
}

map.on('click', function (evt) {
  var coord = ol.proj.toLonLat(evt.coordinate);
  reverseGeocode(coord);
});
```

The response would then look similar to this:

```
{  
   "place_id":"109922016",
   "licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https:\/\/osm.org\/copyright",
   "osm_type":"way",
   "osm_id":"174849788",
   "lat":"40.0498172",
   "lon":"26.2183522194416",
   "display_name":"Çanakkale Martyrs' Memorial, D550, Seddülbahir, Eceabat, Çanakkale, Marmararegion, Türkei",
   "address":{  
      "memorial":"Çanakkale Martyrs' Memorial",
      "road":"D550",
      "village":"Seddülbahir",
      "county":"Eceabat",
      "state":"Marmararegion",
      "country":"Türkei",
      "country_code":"tr"
   },
   "boundingbox":[  
      "40.0496644",
      "40.0499658",
      "26.2181747",
      "26.2185707"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help.